# Should I sealcoat new (few months) asphalt before winter?

Tags: asphalt

I've had a brand new asphalt put in earlier this year beginning of May (temperature hovering ~50s, +/-5 degrees change between day and night). The same contractor is recommending to seal coat it before winter, in the fall.

I would like unbiased answer - should I do it? My main concern is that it is going to get very cold quickly around October/November, and snowy shortly after, and it sounds like 'ideal' temperature is above 50 degrees. Also, another worry is that it is too soon and asphalt did not have enough curing time.

If yes, can you recommend a seal coat for new driveway?

Comment: I've heard that sealcoating is purely cosmetic, but have nothing to back that opinion up.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, new asphalt in a residential application doesn't begin to show surface degradation for at least a few years. By that time, a coat that you apply now will need to be redone anyway.

I'd wait two years. If it still looks brand new, wait two more. There's something to be said for preventative care, but only if it actually extends the life of the product.

Comment: That's been my own experience as well. If untreated for 5 years and under heavy use, things degrade to the point you need to resurface. You can extend the life by resealing every 2-3 years.